# PHP : html form post not invoking mail.php

Tags: php, email

i wrote an HTML code with form , that should invoke a PHP script (mail.php), But when i click submit it is not calling that script and also it is writing all the form contents on top with URL .

Below is my form.

```
<form  method='POST'  action='mail.php' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<div class="form-group "><label for="Company">Company Name </label><input class="form-control" type="text" required="" id="Company" name="Company" required="true" maxlength="100"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Last_Name">Your Name </label><input class="form-control" type="text" required="" id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name" maxlength="80"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Phone">Contact No. </label><input class="form-control" type="number" required="" id="Phone" name="Phone" maxlength="30"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Email">Email </label><input class="form-control" type="text" ftype="email" required="" id="Email" name="Email" maxlength="100"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Description">Your Message </label><textarea class="form-control" id="Description" required="" name="Description"></textarea></div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="submit" id="formsubmit" class="btn btn-xl btn-block btn-primary" value="Submit" title="Submit" name="Submit">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-xl btn-block " name="reset" value="Reset" title="Reset"></div></div>           
</div></form>
```

and here is my mail.php

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
 
        session_start();
        $name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $phone = $_POST['Phone'];
        $message = $_POST['Description'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];
        
        <script> 
             window.location.replace("google URL");
        </script>
    }
?>
```

But whatever i tried , i it is not taking me to google page , nor it is calling that PHP

**URL?Company=student&Last_Name=wer&Phone=1223&Email=qwe%40gmail.com&Description=dummyTrial&Submit=Submit**

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Network:
[!Network Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W55Vr.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `nor it is calling that PHP`...so what _is_ happening instead? You should have a PHP syntax error. Turn on PHP error reporting if you can't see it.

Comment: And if that's your URL then you're not submitting the request as a POST, even though the HTML form code you've shown would definitely cause a POST. Mysterious. Maybe you're executing code which is different than what you've shown here.

Comment: Lastly, unless you've deliberately omitted some code, your mail.php script doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: You don't really need JS for this anyway, PHP can trigger a redirect itself e.g. `header("Location: https://www.google.com");`

Comment: but, it is same as i wrote here , nothing is different in my code which am running @ADyson

Comment: What is the intended results? This code will do nothing with sessions and just send the user to Google. (The script tags should cause an error as already noted)

Comment: `nothing is different`....it must be, because the URL you're reporting indicates a GET request being submitted, not a POST. the `method='POST'` in your form would cause the request to be submitted to `mail.php` alone, without the ? and everything after it - that data would all be inside the body of the request. And then `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { ` in the PHP would return `true` and it would work better. Why not debug your PHP and see if it's actually entering that `if` block? And use your browser's Network tool to check what kind of request is actually sent. Debug your code!

Comment: You _are_running this on a server, right? Like `http://localhost/index.html`? And your server knows how to handle `.php` files?

Comment: i renamed it , but still it is not working . i gave php error reporting on, but no error caught .@brombeer

Comment: Your DevConsole screenshot has `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs...` as title - which gives the impression you are _not_ using your server/localhost though. Can you run a simple test php file on your server? Like `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>`

Answer (score 3):

You are parsing javascript in php, that is not going to work. Try moving the javascript into the body.

```php
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
 
        session_start();
        $name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $phone = $_POST['Phone'];
        $message = $_POST['Description'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];        
    }
?>
<script> 
window.location.replace("google URL");
</script>
```

Or do it with a header location in php:

```php
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
 
        session_start();
        $name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $phone = $_POST['Phone'];
        $message = $_POST['Description'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];        

        header('Location: https://google.com');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried it not working :(

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe the second method works for you.

Comment: but still it is not redirecting my code , no idea why

Comment: @MyselfMe "not working" isn't an error message or a useful problem description. Give proper details of the issue then people don't have to guess. Turn on PHP error reporting, check your JS console / network tool (in the browser) for errors, do some basic debugging etc etc. You wouldn't phone the garage about your car and say "it doesn't work" and expect the mechanic to fix it without a reasonable description of the problem, so why do you expect it from us? We can't run your code, remember. Note my comments above on the main thread, too, especially the one about POST/GET.

Comment: index.html?Company=d&Last_Name=d&Phone=1233&Email=d&Description=d&Submit=Submit

Comment: `index.html`? Shouldn't that be `index.php`??

Comment: Should that not be `mail.php` - your form's action?

Comment: @MyselfMe `index.html` isn't the name of your PHP script....

Comment: but it just calls php, nothing related to php is there in it

Comment: Sorry , i just started studying form

Comment: Gave index.php , no error .but not posting

Comment: Why index.php? Clearly that's not part of it, ignore that comment. And maybe _think_ before just blindly going with suggestions which clearly talk about filenames which aren't in your code! Anyway, visit index.html, then fill in the form on that page and submit it. That will send a request to mail.php. And maybe take some more HTML forms and PHP tutorials, because you seem to be starting from square one.

Comment: but here , i gave post , and action file , but still it is posting it to same page even, i checked the file but couldn't find a single form other than this @ADyson

Comment: `still it is posting it to same page even`...it can't be. **If** you're using the form you've shown, then it **will** post to mail.php when you submit it. Is the form you've shown part of the index.html file? I think either you're not actually using the code you've shown us, or you've somehow got very confused about what you're doing. Unfortunately you're also giving fairly vague descriptions about what you're doing, which is making it harder for us to verify what you're saying or understand precisely what has happened.

Comment: i GOT IT , i accidently gave a form tag , just in between a div, now it is taking me to mail.php .. Thank you @ADyson